# Map from $n$-cube to smash product of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have a question regarding the map:
$$\Phi: I^n \to S^1 \wedge ... \wedge S^1.$$
It is induced by the map $\pi: I \to I / \partial I \cong S^1$.
The wegde is taken $n$ times.

I know that this smash product is homeomorphic to $S^n$. So I could also write down the map $$\Psi: I^n \to S^n.$$ I obtain this map by composing $\Phi$ with the homeomorphism mentioned above.

I'm having difficulties understanding what this map looks like. I know that if $n=1$, then this $\Psi$ is just the quotient map $I \to I/\partial I$. In the case of dimension $n$, I imagine this map to be the one that lies the cube over the sphere and identifies the boundary of the cube with the south pole. Is this the correct way to think about it? Is there an explicit formula for $\Psi$?

Comment: Well $I^n$ is homeomorphic to $D^n$, and $S^n$ is obtained as the quotient $D^n/S^{n-1}$. Of course this is just $I^n/\partial(I^n)$. You can divide up $I^n$ as $I\times\dots\times I$ ($n$ times), as in your question, and get the same answer. In fact $S^{n-1}=\partial D^n\cong \partial (I^n)=(\partial I\times I^{n-1})\cup(I\times \partial I\times I^{n-2})\cup\dots\cup(I^{n-1}\times\partial I)$. The point being that your map is just the quotient projection $D^n\rightarrow D^n/S^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting this map to $I^n\setminus\partial I^n$ gives a homeomorphism to $S^n\setminus *$, as this restriction is the product of the homeomorphisms $I\setminus\partial I\to S^1\setminus *$. All the other points are identified and sent to $*$. It is not hard to see that this is a quotient map: the map $I^n\to (S^1)^n$ is a product of quotient maps between locally compact spaces, and the map $(S^1)^n\to S^n$ is a quotient by definition. So this is just the map collapsing the boundary of $I^n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I understood that it's just a quotient map now. I'm still a bit confused about the smash product though. Is there a way to explicitly write down the homeomorphism from the smash product of the $S^1$ to $S^n$?

Comment: The smash product is the quotient of the $n$-torus $T^n$ by the union of subspaces of the form $S^1\times\dotsb\times *\times\dotsb\times S^1$. In the case $n=2$, this is something you can visualize: take a torus and collapse circles in two different directions. More generally, I think observing that this is the quotient of a cube by its boundary is the easiest way to see it.